# return output using multiple criteria

Tags: r

I am trying to assign behaviors to birds based on their cluster and the angle they are at:

```
new[1:10,]
     date     time    angle cluster
1  23/05/2012 10:16:57 14.07701       2
2  23/05/2012 10:16:58 28.53635       0
3  23/05/2012 10:16:59 28.59663       0
4  23/05/2012 10:17:00 25.11674       0
5  23/05/2012 10:17:01 19.48292       0
6  23/05/2012 10:17:02 17.60478       0
7  23/05/2012 10:17:03 19.33444       1
8  23/05/2012 10:17:04 20.88084       1
9  23/05/2012 10:17:05 21.20995       1
10 23/05/2012 10:17:06 20.76851       1

new$class1[new$cluster=="0"]<-"flying"
new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>="40"]<-"flapping"
new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>="10" & new$angle<="40"]<-"floating"
```

The first line (flying) works, but as soon as I try to add other criteria it does not work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

#### Thanks for all the help. That part of the code does seemto be working, I'm not sure what happened yesterday! I am having problems with the next bit where I try and introduce 2 new variables (X1=lead, and X3=lag)

```
      date     time      angle cluster X1 X2 X3   class1
```

280 23/05/2012 10:21:36 -7.9957740       4  4  4  4 flapping
281 23/05/2012 10:21:37 -7.9653004       4  4  4  4 flapping
282 23/05/2012 10:21:38 -6.2596800       4  2  4  4 flapping
283 23/05/2012 10:21:39 13.9916609       2  2  2  4

new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-1" & new$angle<="10"]<-"flapping"
new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"10" & new$angle<="80"]<-"ascent"
new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-50" & new$angle<="-1" & new$X1=="7"]<-"leap"
new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-50" & new$angle<="-1" & new$X1!="7"]<-"bottom phase"
So in the case above behaviour should be "bottom phase")
Thanks

Thanks for the help. The negative angle was only recognised after I removed the quotation marks.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but there isn't any angle larger that 40 so that's why nothing changes with second line.

Comment: He's just giving the first 10 lines so don't assume there no angle larger than 40.

Comment: Also, does your code run without erorr?

Comment: Hi Vicky, this seems to work fine on the sample data you provided.   When you say it doesnt work, what specifically is happening?  What is letting you know that it does not work?  What happens instead?  Are you getting any warnings about `factor`s?

Comment: Please give us an example where it doesn't work. Also, explain what *doesn't work* means. Show us the output you're looking for and what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the quotes around angle variable, i.e.,

```
new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>=40]<-"flapping"
new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>=10 & new$angle<=40]<-"floating"
```

Comment: Although that is wrong, R is clever enough to convert "40" to numeric. So that shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: True but the fact that he is putting stuff in quotes makes me think that perhaps he has factor variables and not numeric variables so I was hoping my comment might uncover that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. That part of the code does seemto be working, I'm not sure what happened yesterday! I am having problems with the next bit where I try and introduce 2 new variables (X1=lead, and X3=lag)          date     time      angle cluster X1 X2 X3   class1
280 23/05/2012 10:21:36 -7.9957740       4  4  4  4 flapping
281 23/05/2012 10:21:37 -7.9653004       4  4  4  4 flapping
282 23/05/2012 10:21:38 -6.2596800       4  2  4  4 flapping

Comment: The code I used was   new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-1" & new$angle<="10"]<-"flapping"  
 new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"10" & new$angle<="80"]<-"ascent"  
 new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-50" & new$angle<="-1" & new$X1=="7"]<-"leap"  
 new$class1[new$cluster=="4" & new$angle>"-50" & new$angle<="-1" & new$X1!="7"]<-"bottom phase  so the example inthe comment above should be "bottom phase"

Comment: I dont think it recognises the negative numbers in the code.     698 23/05/2012 10:28:34  4.72879440       4  4  4  4       ascent  
699 23/05/2012 10:28:35  0.36821387       4  2  4  4     flapping  
Is there something I can do to specify negative numbers?   Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. The negative angle was only recognised after I removed the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code works fine for me.

```
> new = read.csv("bird.csv",header=T)
> new
         date     time    angle cluster
1  23/05/2012 10:16:57 14.07701       2
2  23/05/2012 10:16:58 28.53635       0
3  23/05/2012 10:16:59 28.59663       0
4  23/05/2012 10:17:00 25.11674       0
5  23/05/2012 10:17:01 19.48292       0
6  23/05/2012 10:17:02 17.60478       0
7  23/05/2012 10:17:03 19.33444       1
8  23/05/2012 10:17:04 20.88084       1
9  23/05/2012 10:17:05 21.20995       1
10 23/05/2012 10:17:06 20.76851       1
> 
> new$class1[new$cluster=="0"]<-"flying"
> new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>="40"]<-"flapping"
> new$class1[new$cluster=="1" & new$angle>="10" & new$angle<="40"]<-"floating"
> new
         date     time    angle cluster   class1
1  23/05/2012 10:16:57 14.07701       2     <NA>
2  23/05/2012 10:16:58 28.53635       0   flying
3  23/05/2012 10:16:59 28.59663       0   flying
4  23/05/2012 10:17:00 25.11674       0   flying
5  23/05/2012 10:17:01 19.48292       0   flying
6  23/05/2012 10:17:02 17.60478       0   flying
7  23/05/2012 10:17:03 19.33444       1 floating
8  23/05/2012 10:17:04 20.88084       1 floating
9  23/05/2012 10:17:05 21.20995       1 floating
10 23/05/2012 10:17:06 20.76851       1 floating
```

Comment: Obviously there is no flapping class1 since in the first 10 lines there was no bird that met that criteria.

Comment: Also, I consider both cluster and angle to be numeric so once again maybe that's your problem.